# Why is previewLayer returning nil when I try to get bounds?

Tags: ios, swift

This view controller is being called from a button on another storyboard. Every time I tap the button I get

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2017-04-16 21:00:39.929042 FaceOnACase[757:377279] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on the line self.previewLayer?.frame = self.previewView.bounds.

I had this code working earlier in a separate, single view app I was working on, but when I transferred the code over and hooked up the IBOutlets, I can't get it working for some reason.

I couldn't find a similar issue, and I'm unsure how to correct this. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CaptureController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    var captureSesssion: AVCaptureSession!
    var cameraOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    @IBOutlet weak var capturedImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        captureSesssion = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
        cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            if (captureSesssion.canAddInput(input)) {
                captureSesssion.addInput(input)
                if (captureSesssion.canAddOutput(cameraOutput)) {
                    captureSesssion.addOutput(cameraOutput)
                    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSesssion)
                    self.previewLayer?.frame = self.previewView.bounds
                    previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                    captureSesssion.startRunning()
                }
            } else {
                print("issue here : captureSesssion.canAddInput")
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    // Take picture button
    @IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
        let previewFormat = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
            kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
            kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
        ]
        settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
        cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }
    // callBack from take picture
    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,  didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,  previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings:  AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings:   AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("error occured : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
            let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
            let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
            print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)
            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
            let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
            self.capturedImage.image = image
        } else {
            print("some error here")
        }
    }
    // This method you can use somewhere you need to know camera permission   state
    func askPermission() {
        print("here")
        let cameraPermissionStatus =  AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        switch cameraPermissionStatus {
        case .authorized:
            print("Already Authorized")
        case .denied:
            print("denied")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry :(" , message: "But  could you please grant permission for camera within device settings",  preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel,  handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .restricted:
            print("restricted")
        default:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: {
                [weak self]
                (granted :Bool) -> Void in
                if granted == true {
                    // User granted
                    print("User granted")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                        //Do smth that you need in main thread
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // User Rejected
                    print("User Rejected")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "WHY?" , message:  "Camera it is the main feature of our application", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                        alert.addAction(action)
                        self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`previewLayer` is *not* returning `nil`. It's `previewView` that is `nil`. Make sure you have hooked this up correctly as an outlet in the storyboard.

Also what you're doing is too early. You cannot start a capture session in `viewDidLoad`. Remember, this means the view *exists*, but it is not even in the interface yet! You at least need an interface in order to start the capture session.

Comment: Okay I checked and I got it hooked up properly. Now, should I put these in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad?

Comment: Because everything seems to be working properly now. Thanks btw!

Comment: I would advise using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, because you are dependent on `self.previewView.bounds` and it won't be set correctly until then. You will need a Bool flag so that your code runs only once (because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called many times).

Comment: So, since viewDidLayoutSubviews doesn't require a Bool arg, I wrap the camera block (starting from captureSession = AVCaptureSession() to the end of the do-try-catch block) in an if statement, setting a var like loadCamera to initially be false but true if it completes?

Comment: Because when I connected the outlet and had it in viewDidLoad() it worked just fine (thanks!), but after I put it in viewDidLayoutSubviews() the view loaded but the camera wasn't working. Again, thanks for the help!